# PrimeReact Dropdown options window scrolls aways from input field while scrolling the screen

Tags: reactjs, primereact

I'm using Dropdown menu from PrimeReact library. I have just noticed that when I press on input field windows pops up and looks as it normally should, picture below.[image]

But when I keep it open and scroll the screen window moves with the screen, which is strange and of course not wished behaviour.

[image]

This is how it's implemented

```
<Dropdown
                  name={`multisports.${index}.multisportType.cost`}
                  value={multisportType.cost}
                  options={sortedMultisportCost}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  placeholder="Select cost"
                />
```

Can You please suggest how can I fix this bug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue reported here: https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/issues/2683

PR submitted to fix it: https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/pull/2757

Comment: Hello. I checked links which You have provided but being honest I cannot figure out how can I implement this solution to my code. Above is the implementation of Dropdown. Can You please suggest how to fix it ?

Comment: You cannot implement it yourself unless you apply that patch and build a custom PrimeReact lib.

Answer (score 0):

Just use appendTo="self" prop

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35393744)